# Faster Approach to Find Parent Child Relationship

Tags: c#, recursion, parent-child, asp.net-mvc-5, processing-efficiency

I have a product structure table like the following:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent</td>
    <td>Component</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123100A</td>
    <td>123201B</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123201B</td>
    <td>123301A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123201B</td>
    <td>123302A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123301A</td>
    <td>123401A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123301A</td>
    <td>123402A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123301A</td>
    <td>123403A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Currently, I populate a list with my product structure and recursively loop through it to get all the base level components of a finished good item.  The finished good item would be 123100A, or any parent that doesn't show up as a component in the list.  In the end, I get a list that looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Parent</td>
    <td>Component</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123100A</td>
    <td>123302A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123100A</td>
    <td>123401A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123100A</td>
    <td>123402A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123100A</td>
    <td>123403A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code I use to recursively loop to find each end component:

```
public void getCapacityComponents(string parPart, string partNum, decimal qtyMultiplier)
    {
        //Start of recursion to get child items
        List<ProductStructure> capacity = new List<ProductStructure>();


        var result = from x in psList
                     join y in partsList on x.parent equals y.part
                     where x.parent == partNum
                     select x;


        //recursive loop through components
        foreach (var x in result)
        {
            ProductStructure mrpProduct = new ProductStructure();
            mrpProduct.parent = x.parent;
            mrpProduct.component = x.component;
            if (x.quantity == 0)
                mrpProduct.quantity = qtyMultiplier;
            else
                mrpProduct.quantity = x.quantity * qtyMultiplier;
            capacity.Add(mrpProduct);
        }

        if (capacity.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var part in capacity)
            {
                getCapacityComponents(parPart, part.component, part.quantity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ProductStructure capacityPart = new ProductStructure();
            capacityPart.parent = parPart;
            capacityPart.component = partNum;
            capacityPart.quantity = qtyMultiplier;
            mrpProductList.Add(capacityPart);
        }
        //End of current solution to get child items
    }
```

I send this function a list of finished good parts and use the MRPProductList to compare the components to all finished goods.  I get the result I want but this takes a very long time to run.  I usually have around 2700 Finished good parts that I need to loop through to get all end component items.

Is there a more efficient way to go through a list to find these items without doing the recursive loop?

Comment: Is this something you could do in the database instead?

Comment: We have also done it within the database recursively but only on a part by part basis, not so much on the bulk side.  It is certainly an option I could try.

Comment: I asked because recursion may be better handled by a database engine.  That being said, you might consider posting your question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)